# Memory leaks in UITableView with NSMutableArray - How to stop them?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I'm pretty new to objective-c development and I'm to the point I'm beginning to test my application for leaks and patching up anything else I may have done wrong originally. I followed the examples from a book I bought and expanded on those ideas. The Leaks instrument is telling me in my tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath method I have a leak and I'm not sure on how to fix it.

Here is the related .h contents:

```
@interface NewsListViewController : UITableViewController<UIActionSheetDelegate> {
NSMutableArray *newsList, *account, *playerList;}
```

And here is the related .m contents:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)ip {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NewsCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [cell autorelease];
}

NSManagedObject *uNews = [newsList objectAtIndex:[ip row]];

NSManagedObjectContext *playerDBContext = [[AppController sharedAppController] managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *playerDBRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *playerDBEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Players"
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:playerDBContext];
[playerDBRequest setEntity:playerDBEntity];

NSPredicate *playerDBPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"playerID=%@", [uNews valueForKey:@"playerID"]];
[playerDBRequest setPredicate:playerDBPredicate];

NSError *playerDBError;

NSArray *playerDBList = [playerDBContext executeFetchRequest:playerDBRequest error:&playerDBError];

[playerDBRequest release];

playerList = [playerDBList mutableCopy];

NSString *playerInformation;

if (![playerDBList count] == 0) {
        NSManagedObject *playerInfo = [playerList objectAtIndex:0];
        playerInformation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@ (%@-%@)", [playerInfo valueForKey:@"playerLastName"],
                                                                          [playerInfo valueForKey:@"playerFirstName"],
                                                                          [playerInfo valueForKey:@"team"],
                                                                          [playerInfo valueForKey:@"position"]];
} else {
    //NSInteger playerID = (NSInteger *)[uNews valueForKey:@"playerID"];
    [self addPlayer:(NSInteger *)[uNews valueForKey:@"playerID"]];
    NSLog(@"%@", [uNews valueForKey:@"playerID"]);
    playerInformation = [uNews valueForKey:@"playerInfo"];
}

cell.textLabel.text = playerInformation;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [uNews valueForKey:@"news"];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;}
```

It's throwing the error on the playerList = [playerDBList mutableCopy]; line - Help with how to fix and an explanation would be greatly appreciated. It's probably from reallocating without releasing but when I've tried using [playerList release]; at the end of the cellForRowAtIndexPath my app crashes.

Comment: What are the specific exceptions, crashes, and leaks?

Comment: The leaked object is listed as either _NSArrayM or Malloc 16 Bytes - in total there are 32 listed in Instruments all pointing to that line. Responsible Library is CoreData and Responsible Frame is -[_PFArray mutableCopyWithZone:]

Comment: Where/how do you release `playerList`?

Comment: I'm currently not - Which I realize is causing the leaking. I've tried calling [playerList release]; as well as also putting playerList = nil; at the end of cellForRowAtIndexPath - but that causes the app to crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties would make this 'just work'.

.h:

```
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *playerList;
...
```

.m:

```
@implementation MyClass 

@synthesize playerList;

... then in your cellForIndexPath method ...

    self.playerList = [[playerDBList mutableCopy] autorelease];

...

- (void)dealloc {
    [playerList release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

A property declared 'retain' will automatically handle memory management when the property is assigned, releasing the old value if it exists before retaining the new one.

Answer (score 1):

The release you tried crashed because the first time through playerlist hasn't ever been assigned and you release a nil.  But the second time through it has something and you leak it.  Whenever I reuse a retaining pointer like that, I do

```
if( playerList )
   [playerList release];
playerList = [playerDBList mutableCopy];
```

just to be safe.

Comment: Also be sure to release `playerList` in `dealloc`

Comment: I knew it was going to be something simple. Thanks for the answer!